# sql query with space in the value

Tags: java, sql, orm, openjpa

How do I write where clause where the value has spaces:

Actually I am using openJPA and I have to set parameter.
The value i will be setting has a space, eg:
String somevalue="firstname lastname";
query.setparameter(somevalue);

I did this but doesnot work. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What does your table look like?

Comment: See if the name you're typing has apostrophes.  If so, you'll need to escape them with double apostrophes:   `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name = 'Miles O''Brien';`  Also, if you need to do pattern matching (e.g. if there are stray spaces) rather than an exact match, look into the LIKE keyword.

Comment: Please don't change the entire contents of a question, because then any existing answers don't make sense. Instead, just add clarifications.

Comment: Might I suggest that parameterizing queries instead of concating strings to create dynamic queries may help with this type of thing as well.

Answer (score 2):

That should work.  The space within the quotes is valid.  Perhaps there are spaces after the lastname, or the casing of lastname is incorrect.

Comment: actually query.setParameter(value with space); is not working
do I need to do some special thing with query.setparameter()

Answer (score 1):

That syntax does indeed work; you must be typing in a name that does not exist.

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE FOO (name TEXT);
sqlite> INSERT INTO FOO VALUES('joe smith');
sqlite> SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE name = 'joe smith';
joe smith
```

If this is a one-off search, you might be better off trying [the `LIKE` operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) to find the match:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE name LIKE '%smith%';
joe smith
```

Comment: actually query.setParameter(value with space); is not working
do I need to do some special thing with query.setparameter()

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with that query.

If it's not returning results, it's because you've got a problem with your data. Are you storing as 'char' or 'varchar'? If it's 'char', then you'll have extra padding characters in there to watch for.

Comment: actually query.setParameter(value with space); is not working
do I need to do some special thing with query.setparameter()